# Detecting if an extension is installed from another extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to find out whether an extension exists from a second extension?

First off, a bit of background: I have an extension which is overriding the bookmark manager. The client also wants a history manager, which I know can't be done in one extension.

My proposal was to create two extensions, one of which acts as a 'core' as well, handling authentication with the client's API. I've got the two talking together and the auth is working fine, but I'm struggling to cope with the case of the core extension not being installed. I want to show a prompt to install the core one, if it's not there.

I could send a message and capture `chrome.extension.lastError`, but is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Synchronous messages would be a boon here too I imagine....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Cross-extension messaging](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) API to send a message from extension 2 to extension 1. If extension 1 doesn't respond then you can prompt the user to install extension 1. I built two Chrome extensions to test this idea and it worked great.

Here are the files zipped up if you want to download them and try them yourself. Here is a screencast showing the working example on YouTube http://youtu.be/6u4tIH6Xfcg

## Extension 2 (Subordinate)

### manifest.json

```js
{
    "name": "Subordinate Chrome Extension Example",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "This is an example extension for StackOverflow that requires a master/companion Google Chrome extension to be installed for it to work",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
}
```

### background.js

```js
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        switch (request.directive) {
        case "popup-click":
            // check to see if master extension 1 is installed
            chrome.extension.sendMessage('jfhngkelgcildagdkgenelgaaaphlghb', {directive: "ping"}, function(extensionResponse) {
                if (extensionResponse && extensionResponse.data == 'pong') {
                    console.log("The master extension 1 is installed!");
                } else {
                    console.log("The master extension 1 is not installed");
                }
                sendResponse({});
            });
            return true; // required to return true if we want to sendResponse() later since the cross chrome extension message passing is asynchronus
            break;
        default:
            // helps debug when request directive doesn't match
            alert("Unmatched request of '" + request + "' from script to background.js from " + sender);
        }
    }
);
```

### popup.html

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            body { min-width:250px; text-align: center; }
            #click-me { font-size: 20px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id='click-me'>Click Me!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

### popup.js

```js
function clickHandler(e) {
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({directive: "popup-click"}, function(response) {
        this.close(); // close the popup when the background finishes processing request
    });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById('click-me').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
})
```

## Extension 1 (Master/Companion)

### manifest.json

```js
{
    "name": "Master Chrome Extension Example",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "This is an example extension for StackOverflow that is required for a subordinate/companion Google Chrome extension to work",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
}
```

### background.js

```js
chrome.extension.onMessageExternal.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (sender.id == 'ikofjngppooeeendkfenaiedmlmfjmkb') { // restricting cross extension api to known extension
        if (request.directive == 'ping') {
            sendResponse({
                data: 'pong'
            });
        }
    }
});
```